# How to map single column value of a row in for loop in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext  
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)  
test = hive_context.table("dbname.tablename")    
iterate = test.map(lambda p:(p.survey_date,p.pro_catg,p.metric_id))  
 for ite in iterate.collect() :       
   v = ite.map(lambda p:p.metric_id) 
   print (v)
```

Above code is giving error in for loop.How to print a single column with out changing above mapping because further i would like to write the code as

```
for ite in iterate.collect():  
   for ite11 in secondtable.collect() :   
       if ite.metric_id.find(ite11.column1)  
         result.append(ite , ite11)
```

Kindly any one help on this

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for error when running:**

```
for ite in iterate.collect() :       
   v = ite.map(lambda p:p.metric_id)
```

The result of iterate.collect() is not RDD, it is a python list (or something like that).

**`map` can be execute on RDD, and can't be executed on python-list.**

In general `collect()` is NOT recommended to use in spark

The following should perform similar operation without error:

```
iterate = test.map(lambda p:(p.survey_date,p.pro_catg,p.metric_id))  
   v = iterate.map(lambda (survey_date,pro_catg,metric_id): metric_id)
   print (v.collect())
```

Comment: I have a question. Thanks in advance!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964179/pyspark-mapping-multiple-variables

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got one more solution to map single column value in for loop as

```
for ite in iterate.collect():
  for itp in prod.collect():    
    if itp[0] in ite[1]: result.append(p)   
print(result)
```

It works fine. Instead of `in` we can use `find` as

```
if ite[1].find(itp[0]): result.append(p)
```

Comment: I have a questions. Thanks in advance!`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964179/pyspark-mapping-multiple-variables