# pySpark mapping multiple variables

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapping

The code below maps values and column names of my reference df with my actual dataset, finding exact matches and if an exact match is found, return the `OutputValue`.  However, I'm trying to add the rule that when `PrimaryValue = DEFAULT` to also return the `OutputValue`.

The solution I'm trying out to tackle this is to create a new dataframe with null values - since there was no match provided by code below. Thus the next step would be to target the null values whose corresponding `PrimaryValue = DEFAULT` to replace null by the `OutputValue`.

```
  #create a map based on columns from reference_df
  map_key = concat_ws('\0', final_reference.PrimaryName, final_reference.PrimaryValue)
  map_value = final_reference.OutputValue

  #dataframe of concatinated mappings to get the corresponding OutputValues from reference table
  d = final_reference.agg(collect_set(array(concat_ws('\0','PrimaryName','PrimaryValue'), 'OutputValue')).alias('m')).first().m
  #display(d)

  #iterate through mapped values 
  mappings = create_map([lit(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(d)])

  #dataframe with corresponding matched OutputValues
  dataset = datasetM.select("*",*[ mappings[concat_ws('\0', lit(c), col(c))].alias(c_name) for c,c_name in matched_List.items()]) 
  display(dataset)
```

Comment: do you mean when the requested col-name from `primaryLookupAttributeName_List` does not exists in datasetMatchedPortfolio which will yield ERROR? so you want to add a default name to go through the ERROR?

Comment: @jxc, so there's no error. It simply populates the column with null. The dataset will never include `DEFAULT` , it will have a regular value. When `PrimaryLookupAttributeName` is DEFAULT then I will like to replace those null (no match found) by the corresponding `OutputItemNameByValue`. I will update my question with more info!

Comment: very likely, you just need coalesce, for example: `coalesce(mappings[concat_ws('\0', lit(c), col(c))], lit("DEFAULT")).alias(c_name)`. make sure to import pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce

Comment: @jxc, sorry, are you proposing to do this to the null df or to include it as part of my initial `datasetPrimaryAttributes_False = `

Comment: @jxc, would your recommend including a udf here with if/else/ elif loop? I have 3 cases for matched: 1) if match is found, copy the outputValue, 2) if DeFAULT, copy outputValue, 3) if no match at all and null, "Lookup not found".  Otherwise, my idea so far is to continue building filter down dataframes until my last case and all dataset values have a corresponding updated value.

Comment: from your updated df, the `PrimaryLookupAttributeValue = DEFAULT` does exist in `LeaseStatus` what is exactly your expectation? are you looking to add some entries in mappings? I dont think we need udf here..

Comment: if I understand you correctly, for your sample in reference_df, we will need to fill null value of LeaseStatus by `Pending`, and fill null values in `LeaseRecoveryType` by "Lookup not found"?

Comment: @jxc, yes, that's exactly what I'm shooting for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From discussion in comments, I think you just need to add a default mappings from the existing one and then use [coalease](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce)() function to find the first non-null value, see below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, array, concat_ws, lit, col, create_map, coalesce

# skip some old code

d    
#[['LeaseStatus\x00Abandoned', 'Active'],
# ['LeaseStatus\x00DEFAULT', 'Pending'],
# ['LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross-modified', 'Modified Gross'],
# ['LeaseStatus\x00Archive', 'Expired'],
# ['LeaseStatus\x00Terminated', 'Terminated'],
# ['LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross w/base year', 'Modified Gross'],
# ['LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross', 'Gross']]

# original mapping
mappings = create_map([ lit(j) for i in d for j in i ])

# default mapping
mappings_default = create_map([ lit(j.split('\0')[0]) for i in d if i[0].upper().endswith('\x00DEFAULT') for j in i ])
#Column<b'map(LeaseStatus, Pending)'>

# a set of available PrimaryLookupAttributeName
available_list = set([ i[0].split('\0')[0] for i in d ])
# {'LeaseRecoveryType', 'LeaseStatus'}

# use coalesce to find the first non-null values from mappings, mappings_defaul etc
datasetPrimaryAttributes_False = datasetMatchedPortfolio.select("*",*[ 
  coalesce(
    mappings[concat_ws('\0', lit(c), col(c))],
    mappings_default[c],
    lit("Not Specified at Source" if c in available_list else "Lookup not found")
  ).alias(c_name) for c,c_name in matchedAttributeName_List.items()])
```

**Some explanation**:

(1) d is a list of lists retrieved from the reference_df, we use a list comprehension `[ lit(j) for i in d for j in i ]` to flatten this to a list and apply the flattened list to the `create_map` function:

(2) The mappings_default is similar to the above, but add a `if` condition to serve as a filter and keep only entries having PrimaryLookupAttributeValue (which is the first item of the inner list `i[0]`) ending with `\x00DEFAULT` and then use `split` to strip PrimaryLookupAttributeValue(which is basically `\x00DEFAULT`) off from the map_key.

Comment: can you explain `mappings`

Comment: I understand it actually. I'll rewrite them to describe variable names , thanks! Also, I just realized that I actually have another scenario. 1) if match is found, copy the outputValue, 2) if DEFAULT, copy outputValue, 3) if no match at all and null, "Lookup not found" 4) if there are null values in dataset. For example, dataset.LeaseRecoveryType has nulls, so there is no match not because there is no reference_table value but bc the actual dataset does not provide a value. So if the dataset value = null, then return " Not Specified at Source" ....@jxc

Comment: don't think it's working. I still only get "Look up not found" for when dataset.LeaseRecoveryType = null. Playing around with it right now @jxc

Comment: how about change `if c in available_list` to `if c not in available_list`?

Comment: Yes! I tried that too and it works .. however, struggling to understand why exactly

Comment: it was just a logic mistake in my old code, if `c` is already in the available_list, the result should be `Not Specified at Source` instead of 'Lookup not found'.

Comment: @jgtrz, what is the question?

Comment: @jgtrz, do you mean the order of columns? since matchedAttributeName_List is a dict, thus the order of columns from list comprehension by iterating through matchedAttributeName_List.items() is not guaranteed.

Comment: follow-up question on the code your answer: within ```datasetPrimaryAttributes_False``` , specifically, what would the anticipated output be if there are two rows within ```mappings ``` (d) with the same names but different values; such as : ```#[['LeaseStatus\x00Abandoned', 'Active'],
# ['LeaseStatus\x00Abandoned', 'Pending']```, how would happen to ```datasetPrimaryAttributes_False.mappings```